# Elegant ways to generate lists based on conditions using information from a input file

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a `file` which looks like following,

```
file= '/user/home/file.txt'

file

[SKY]
/user/home/repo/study

[EARTH]
/user/home/learn/objects

[LOCAL]
/user/home/teach/files

[SAMP]
VKP
RNP
SAS

[TYPE]
HGH

[SAMP_ID]
VKP_TP_MA
RNP_TP_NA
SAS_SAS

[ENV]
....
```

Now I need to transfer the items from `[SAMP]` and `[SAMP_ID]` to a list.
This is what I am doing which is giving what I need. But any better or elegant solution would be great.

So my lists are `samp` and `samp_id`, and here is the solution and I am using currently,

```
samp = []
samp_id = []
sampSection = False
samp_idection  =  False

for line in open(file, 'r'):
    if len(line.strip()) == 0:
        sampSection = False
        continue
    if line.strip() == '[SAMP]':
        sampSection = True
        continue
    elif line.startswith('['):
        sampSection = False
        continue
    if sampSection:
        samp.append(line.strip())
        continue

for line in open(file, 'r'):
    if len(line.strip()) == 0:
        samp_idection = False
        continue
    if line.strip() == '[SAMP_ID]':
        samp_idection = True
        continue
    elif line.startswith('['):
        samp_idection = False
        continue
    if samp_idection:
        samp_id.append(line.strip())
        continue
```

And `samp` and `samp_id` looks as follows,

```
samp =['VKP','RNP', 'SAS']
samp_id=['VKP_TP_MA','RNP_TP_NA', 'SAS_SAS']
```

It would be great if there is any simpler solutions in this case.

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to find the name of your file format, it looks like an INI or TOML. `configparser` could maybe be the package to look for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would parse the entire file with a dict, without opening and iterating the file twice:

```
result    = {}
current   = None
with open("my_file.txt") as fd: #To close the file automatically
    for line in fd:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith('['):
            current = line.strip('[]')
            result[current] = []
            continue
        if current is None: continue
        if line: result[current].append(line)

 #Or just use the dictionary
 samp    = result['SAMP']
 samp_id = result['SAMP_ID']
```

If you really do not want to keep any other tag:

```
fields    = set(('SAMP','SAMP_ID'))
result    = {}
current   = None
with open("my_file.txt") as fd:
    for line in fd:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith('['):
            current = line.strip('[]')
            if current not in fields: current = None
            else: result[current] = []
            continue
        if current is None: continue
        if line: result[current].append(line)
```

Comment: Thanks for both solutions, the first one is simpler and I am going with that.